# How should I update both array and <ul> at the same time using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I have this code , and I want when I click the button both `li` and the array show the same value at the same time.
I mean in this code when I click on the button

`ul` would be updated with input value and the array is empty , then when I enter new value and click the button , again ul would be updated correctly but the array shows me previous value of input.

here is the code :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const App = () => {
    
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    
    const addItem = () => {
        setItems([ ... items, {
            id : items.length,
            value : value
        }])
        
        console.log(items)
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <input type = "text" onChange = { (e) => setValue(e.target.value)} value = {value} />
        <br />
        <button onClick = {addItem}>Add value</button>
        <ul>
            {
                items.map(item => <li key = {item.id}>{item.value}</li>)
            }
        </ul>
        </>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: setting the state is asynchronous, so you would no see the updated `items` right after the `setItems` call. You will see it in the next update though

Comment: so how should I do What I want?

Comment: Your code works fine, only the `console.log` is not correct. If you want to log it add a `useEffect( () => console.log(items), [items]);`

Comment: actually I want it to add my record in an phone book app
and I want to have add / delete / search
does it work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is getting updated but since the setState is async you can't see that instantly, instead add a useEffect on items to do an action or check when the items have updated

Try it like this

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const App = () => {

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

// this informs you about updation of items.
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(items);
}, [items]);

const addItem = () => {
    setItems([ ... items, {
        id : items.length,
        value : value
    }])
    
}

return (
    <>
    <input type = "text" onChange = { (e) => setValue(e.target.value)} value = {value} />
    <br />
    <button onClick = {addItem}>Add value</button>
    <ul>
        {
            items.map(item => <li key = {item.id}>{item.value}</li>)
        }
    </ul>
    </>
    );
}
export default App;
```

[Running code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-stonebraker-s2elw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks alot , But can i pass the function ``addItem`` to useEffect?
I want to do it like that
or any other way that helps me to do so

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean by pass, if you want to take any action when items are changed you can place that code inside the useEffect i just defined which will be called when items change. Is this what you are looking for?